# Magento 2.3: Backorder is not working. how its work?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, backorder

Backorder is not working on Magento 2.3. How it works?

[image]

Comment: I have enabled these two options but its not working

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html official guide?

Comment: yes but it not show add to cart button

Answer (score 1):

My team ran into this issue on a Magento v2.3.1 build and had to enable MSI to get things working. Once you've done this, make sure that you are able to set a negative Out-of-stock Threshold.

Though it isn't explicit in [Magento's Documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html), and might actually be a current bug, if you're on v2.3.x of Magento, you'll need to enable MSI for Backorders to function properly. You can read read more about MSI and how to enable it [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/)

**UPDATE: it is a bug**
The fix for the bug is in this commit [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6f4df9be6a8f2a43b08b3831821d01fe6f1e4c2f), and will likely be merged into the next version of 2.3. If you're on Commerce or Commerce Cloud, you should be able to reach out to support for a patch. With this fix, you will **not** need to enable MSI.

Answer (score 0):

Please check after Clear cache and Reindex

if still not working then

Can You please check Back-order Settings on individual product Edit tag on admin

Click on 'Advanced Inventory' Below Quantity field.